# ggplot2: geom_pointrange() facet_grid() with coord_flip() and free scales

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to generate a graph with the estimates and confidence intervals from the same regression for a number of countries. I ran the regressions using `dplyr`'s `group_by(country)`, and then I aggregated all the results into a data frame with `broom`'s `tidy()`.

When creating the graph from this data frame (called `bycountry1`), I run the following code:

```
ggplot(bycountry1, aes(x = country, y = estimate, ymin = estimate - std.error * 2, ymax = estimate + std.error * 2)) + 
   geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = "black", lty = 2) +
   geom_pointrange() + 
   coord_flip() + facet_grid(. ~ term, scales = "free")
```

[image: here is the graph I get]

This is what I want, except that I'd like to have the scales for each box to be different, so that all of them would look more like the `religious1`box. Since that is the one with most variability, it dominates the scale, and then in most of the other boxes you cannot see the variance. As the code above shows, I did indicate `scales = "free"` in `facet_grid()` and I tried all the variants, also with `facet_wrap()`, and I cannot get this to work.

Comment: How about using `geom_errorbarh` instead of `coord_flip` to get horizontal error bars?

Comment: That's a good idea. Thanks! I had tried it before and it didn't look great, but I just saw that you can modify the `height` of the `geom_errorbarh`, and also add a `geom_point` to get exactly what I was looking for. I will now add an answer with your suggestion. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the suggestion of aosmith, I made it work using `geom_errorbarh` and removing `coord_flip()`. I also had to set the `height` of the `geom_errorbarh` to 0 and add a `geom_point` for the estimate. Here is the code:

```
ggplot(bycountry1, aes(y = country, x = estimate, xmin = estimate - std.error * 2, xmax = estimate + std.error * 2)) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, colour = "black", lty = 2) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_errorbarh(height = 0) + 
  facet_grid(. ~ term, scales = "free")
```

And the resulting image

[image]