# Increase space between x-axis factors in ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am using the geom_pointrange function in ggplot2 in order to plot the spread of some measurement over different condition for 5 subjects. In order not to have the subjects overlap I have constructed the plot as follows:

```
Final = structure(list(Subject = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), 
    X00.conditionName = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("EyeClose-Haptic", "mixed-Haptic_Visual", 
    "only-Haptic", "only-Visual"), class = "factor"), X03.totalTargetNumber = c(2L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L), Accuracy = c(0.075870763, 
    0.0907863686, 0.0222156611, 0.0492028585333333, 0.0301178471, 
    0.0736098328666667, 0.0329723832, 0.0455095300666667, 0.065151615, 
    0.0979033533333333, 0.0247176775, 0.0335825226666667, 0.027385248, 
    0.0462643053333333, 0.037272505, 0.0652166726666667, 0.043005086, 
    0.061848328, 0.031106749, 0.0275656054, 0.026701889, 0.0373967466666667, 
    0.028998468, 0.03219287, 0.0597213356, 0.0851717708333333, 
    0.030286913, 0.0779058462666667, 0.043368508, 0.051437624, 
    0.029002474, 0.0479204566666667, 0.094555739, 0.0856268291666667, 
    0.031908514, 0.0310441326666667, 0.036311762, 0.0496942306666667, 
    0.054625148, 0.0482682121666667), upperCI = c(0.116082073022708, 
    0.139632763787946, 0.0315087794760623, 0.0727058964327625, 
    0.0468512606854127, 0.116787586356955, 0.0444933233012107, 
    0.062820743812494, 0.0858551911272202, 0.136013260005381, 
    0.0327074347874691, 0.0460471773903695, 0.035302995136302, 
    0.0740077338495226, 0.0641795522210299, 0.131047110446756, 
    0.0572545979325947, 0.0809511078363974, 0.0414215170576924, 
    0.0341480438532189, 0.0382253716300962, 0.0519626825555577, 
    0.0377955915789704, 0.0430125127419472, 0.0903928001427357, 
    0.114245467448517, 0.0461054194398361, 0.129350863514659, 
    0.0635159480110737, 0.0717647837071829, 0.0371919026867606, 
    0.0615899295823839, 0.170222051412597, 0.128502458351433, 
    0.046712862081242, 0.0388340720489338, 0.0574188259607336, 
    0.0786845830951613, 0.0844193698576058, 0.0784830058409822
    ), lowerCI = c(0.0356594529772922, 0.0419399734120541, 0.0129225427239377, 
    0.0256998206339042, 0.0133844335145873, 0.0304320793763786, 
    0.0214514430987893, 0.0281983163208393, 0.0444480388727798, 
    0.059793446661286, 0.0167279202125309, 0.0211178679429639, 
    0.019467500863698, 0.0185208768171441, 0.0103654577789701, 
    -0.000613765113422152, 0.0287555740674053, 0.0427455481636026, 
    0.0207919809423076, 0.0209831669467811, 0.0151784063699038, 
    0.0228308107777757, 0.0202013444210296, 0.0213732272580528, 
    0.0290498710572643, 0.0560980742181497, 0.0144684065601638, 
    0.0264608290186746, 0.0232210679889263, 0.0311104642928171, 
    0.0208130453132394, 0.0342509837509495, 0.018889426587403, 
    0.0427511999819006, 0.017104165918758, 0.0232541932843995, 
    0.0152046980392664, 0.0207038782381721, 0.0248309261423941, 
    0.0180534184923511), CondLevel = c("EyeClose-Haptic2", "EyeClose-Haptic3", 
    "mixed-Haptic_Visual2", "mixed-Haptic_Visual3", "only-Haptic2", 
    "only-Haptic3", "only-Visual2", "only-Visual3", "EyeClose-Haptic2", 
    "EyeClose-Haptic3", "mixed-Haptic_Visual2", "mixed-Haptic_Visual3", 
    "only-Haptic2", "only-Haptic3", "only-Visual2", "only-Visual3", 
    "EyeClose-Haptic2", "EyeClose-Haptic3", "mixed-Haptic_Visual2", 
    "mixed-Haptic_Visual3", "only-Haptic2", "only-Haptic3", "only-Visual2", 
    "only-Visual3", "EyeClose-Haptic2", "EyeClose-Haptic3", "mixed-Haptic_Visual2", 
    "mixed-Haptic_Visual3", "only-Haptic2", "only-Haptic3", "only-Visual2", 
    "only-Visual3", "EyeClose-Haptic2", "EyeClose-Haptic3", "mixed-Haptic_Visual2", 
    "mixed-Haptic_Visual3", "only-Haptic2", "only-Haptic3", "only-Visual2", 
    "only-Visual3")), .Names = c("Subject", "X00.conditionName", 
"X03.totalTargetNumber", "Accuracy", "upperCI", "lowerCI", "CondLevel"
), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = "data.frame")


require(ggplot2)

pdf("Pilot2.pdf", w = 12, h = 8)
limits <- aes(ymax = upperCI, ymin=lowerCI)
BaseLayer = ggplot(data = Final, aes (x = X00.conditionName, y = Accuracy, color = Subject, group = Subject ))
BaseLayer + geom_pointrange(limits, position=position_dodge(width=1), size = 1.5) + 
theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14), axis.title=element_text(size=14), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 25, hjust = 1)) + 
facet_grid (.~X03.totalTargetNumber) + ggtitle ("Pilot 2") + xlab ("Condition")
dev.off()
```

[image: Plot for those who do not want to rune the example]

As you can see the x-axis is discrete, and the points are very "crowded", so that it is difficult to tell apart the different categories.

Is there a way to increase the space between the different categories ?

Answer (score 0):

The best solutoin is to use facets to create 8 separate tall and skinny plots with all these features that are separated by a thin white gutter between them with a solid label at the top. You could keep or lose X-axis labels. It creates one figure of 8 graphs that communicates better than on big graph.

Like this:[Stack-ggplot2-geom-pointrange-facet-grid-with-coord-flip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803842/ggplot2-geom-pointrange-facet-grid-with-coord-flip-and-free-scales)

except yours would be verticle

Comment: Not sure of this solution, or maybe I am missing something.
If I keep the aes (x = X00.conditionName,  y = Accuracy, color = Subject, group = Subject ) and then I facet over a combination of Condition and Level, as you suggest, I still get the 4 conditions plotted within each facet, that is clearly not good.

Comment: Yes, but having each X category on its own plot, then the difference between each subject (relative to the category would be clearly obvious and it would be much easier to know if you were looking at the first only-Haptic or the last mixed-Haptic_Visual. Make two sets of four facets with each condition on its own...and two figures, 2 & 3